# Rails4- Sunspot- fulltext params[:search] always returns no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

I am using Rails 4 and I am trying to use the Sunspot gem to implement a search engine for my website, but my search always returns no results. I have confirmed that the text I am searching is in fact in my `:title` or `:text` attributes in my Content model.

My `Content.rb` model:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
        string :title
        text :text
    end
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :text, presence: true
    has_many :links
    validates_associated :links
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :links
end
```

My search form located in `application.html.haml`:

```
  = form_tag search_path, :method => :get do
%p
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
  = submit_tag "Search"
```

My `contents_controller`.rb controller:

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def search
        if params[:search]
            @search = Content.search do
                fulltext params[:search]
            end
            @query = params[:search]
            @content = @search.results
        else
            @content = Content.all
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
  ...
  gem 'sunspot_rails'
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
  ...
```

My `search.html.haml` file that is called after `def search` in my `Contents Controller`:

```
-if @content.empty? || @query == nil
    %p="No results found for: #{@query}"
-elsif !@query.empty?
    %p="Your search results for #{@query}"
-@content.each do |c|
    %h1.content-title=link_to removeHTML(c.title), content_path(c)
    %p.content-text=removeHTML(c.text.split[0..25].join(" ")) + " ..."
```

What's happening in the code above is that my `@content` is **always** empty. This occurs after the line `@content = @search.results`. I have verified this because if I remove the line and call `@content = Content.all`, it displays all of my Content objects, as expected.

Can anyone help me understand why `@search.results` returns nil?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like you need to reindex data with:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

You can fetch `Content.all` because you're doing it with bypassing solr, with query you're using search engine which returns always empty set because it doesn't have any indices.

Comment: Thank you so much! When running that command, it told me to add the gem `progress_bar`. After doing that, it works!

Comment: You should always reindex after changing `searchable` block, without it solr won't fail but you won't get data from new fields.

Comment: @Matrix: is your model really indexing? Did you see progress bar with some numbers on it? Maybe you've got some logic in your `searchable` block which causes such behaviour.

Comment: I use `index!` method too but nothing more. Where I have to look at to see this progress bar? What can I do if there is no index. What is the good why if `index!` and `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` unwork?! thx.

Comment: When you're using rake task you should see some progress bar there, even if you have just one object which can be indexed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, here is my Modal 
`searchable do
    text :title, :default_boost => 2
    text :description
  end`
Controller Code
`@search = Sunspot.search(MobAd) do
      fulltext params[:q]
    end`
and I ran reindex, restarted solr and rails server but still no results.